# My app shows no internet when connected to portable router

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, router

I have the following code check if I have active internet connection:

```
private boolean hasNetworkAccess() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.screens.company").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlc.connect();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("NETWORK", "Error checking internet connection.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I'm connected to my Wi-Fi at home / connected to my phone's hotspot / connected directly to my router - everything is OK and it shows I have active connection.

When every I'm connecting my computer to an Portable Router (TP-LINK) I get the error.

What could be the error just I'm my portable router?

P.S I checked everything else is working when I'm connected to the router like internet browser, YouTube, etc.

Error stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.screens.company/80.179.142.52 (port 80) after 3000ms
```

Comment: You should log the `IOException` and post the full exception details.

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.screens.company/80.179.142.52 (port 80) after 3000ms

Comment: You may just have a slow network. If you increase the connect timeout, does it work?

Comment: now the connection is on 20000 ms... still not working

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- Check to make sure it is `connected to a network`:

---

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

---

- Alternate  solution

---

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        return !address.equals("");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Log error
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

-Permission  required

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Still everything is working but I get no internet connection

Comment: Have you given the `permission` of `Internet`

Comment: Ofcourse, when I'm connected to my home Wifi - everything is okay.